# How to specify in sbt a specific ivy "latest strategy" to use

Tags: sbt, resolver

I'm configuring **build.sbt** to load dependency libraries, and for one I want to use **'latest.revision'**. How do I specify Ivy's "latest strategy" to use to consider the "latest"?

I'm using:

```
"com.foo.boo" % "something" % "latest.integration"
```

If there was built/published:
**something-2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar**
and than later
**something-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar**

resolution brings:
**something-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar**
which seems to be "latest-time" strategy, where as I need latest by version, that is **something-2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar**